# javascript to rotate an image

Tags: javascript

i have rotating image in my webpage.
 link is below:

http://equosinfotech.com/testdemo/test.html

everything works fine as i wanted, i just want to slow down the rotation speed of the image as its too fast and i am not able to find a way to slow it down.

(you can see the code from the page source)

i just need anyone to help me to slow down the rotation.

javascript i am using:

```
    var stop = function (){
       $("#image").rotate({

  angle:0, 
  animateTo:0, 
  callback: stop,
  easing: function (x,t,b,c,d){        // t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c:         change In value, d: duration
              return c*(t/d)+b;
          }
       });
    }

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    rotation();​
        $("#image").rotate({ 
bind: 
{ 
    mouseover : function() { 
    stop();
    },
    mouseout : function() { 
    rotation();
    }
} 
});
    });
var rotation = function() {
$("#image").rotate({

    angle: 0,
    animateTo: 360,
    callback: rotation,
    easing: function(x, t, b, c, d) { // t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
        return c * (t / d) + b;
    }
});
    }
```

Comment: Always include the relevant code and markup **in the question itself**, don't just link. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add in your code, to `$("#image").rotate({..` the `duration:2000,` , or how many secconds you want (2000 is 2 sec. in millisecconds).

Comment: i have put    duration:10000,  belo code                              var rotation = function() {
    $("#image").rotate({
     duration:10000,
        angle: 0,
        animateTo: 360,
        callback: rotation,
        easing: function(x, t, b, c, d) { // t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
            return c * (t / d) + b;
        }
    });

Comment: it actually slows the rotation but after mouseout only not on the page load

Comment: can you suggest where shold i put duration so that i by defalt on page load slows the rotation?

Comment: you can check the link again to see the changes.                      http://equosinfotech.com/testdemo/test.html